# How do I use the user input as part of an output?

Tags: linux, bash, user-input

My task given:

> Create a script that would do the following.
>
> 1. Prompt the user for their name and save it to a variable named myname. Have the script reply back to the user, with a welcome (be
>    sure to include their name in the reply.
> 2. Prompt the user if they would like to play a game. Use a while statement.
>
> Note: Use the value of 1 or 0 for the input as 1=yes and 0=no. The
> while loop needs to have different syntax if characters are used
> verses number values. Write the this code to test if your while
> statement is correct.
>
> 3. Have the user play a greater then, less than game. Have them enter 2 numbers from 1-99. Have the program determine if the first number is
>    larger than the second number or the other way around.
>
> Use an if, then, else statement.
>
> Prompt the user if they would like to play again. (Include their name
> in the prompt) Note: This is part of the while statement in Procedure
> 2.
>
> If the user does not want to play any more, thank the user (by their
> name).

**How would I include the player's name in the play again prompt and how would I thank the user by their name if they don't want to play again?**

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Session11-Lab

read -p "Enter Your Name: "  myname
echo "Welcome $myname!"

game=1

while [ $game -eq 1 ]     
do
  echo $game
  read -p "Would you like to play a game?" game

  read -p "Enter a number between 1 and 99:" num1
  read -p "enter another number between 1 and 99:" num2

  if (($num1 > $num2)) ; then
        echo "the first number is larger"
  else
        echo "the second number is larger"
  fi
  read -p "play again (1 or 0)" game

  done

exit 0
```

Comment: sorry first time using this website ill fix it

Comment: Some other things that may be useful for you... [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc. Shellcheck is an important tool.

Comment: Use the myname variable in the prompt exactly like you do in the welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I include the players name in the play again prompt? ...

You interpolate variables in bash strings like so:

```
read -p "$myname, play again? (1 or 0)" game
```

> ... and how would I thank the user by their name if they don't want to play again?

Add this before the end of while loop to break and exit the game if the user enters `0`:

```
[ $game == 0 ] && break
```

And after the end of the while loop:

```
echo "Thanks for playing $myname!"
```